# Spring 4 Restful Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have just been experimenting with Spring 4 security.  I am using the following method to map the secured endpoints:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/hello/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/hello/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

It occurred to me that if I had a lot of endpoints that the .antMatchers structure could become cumbersome.

Just curious to know if there is an alternative approach that may be more "manageable" - I guess this is a bit subjective?

Comment: Consider [XML Configuration](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/trunk/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/security.xml#L34) if the Java way is getting too cumbersome for you.

Comment: It is a bit ironic in the sense that Java Config is meant to avoid the "complexity" of XML - in this case XML may in fact have more clarity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest to have a method to just add the ant matchers. May be a Map for the path to role mapping and feed the map into that method to add the matchers.

Comment: Thank you for this thought - I will try to build something.